# How to stop Firefox's session restore from loading all of my tabs at once?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, browser-tabs

When I use Firefox I often have many tabs and many windows open (even more so now that they have panorama). I often use the session restore feature because I don't want to lose all my open windows when installing a new add-on or restarting my computer for updates.

However, with so many tabs open it takes a really, really long time for Firefox to load all the tabs.

I'm looking for an extension that will open a placeholder tab for all of the websites on session restore but won't actually load the page until I click on that tab to bring it to focus.

Basically, it would look like I had 40 tabs open, but until I click on that tab, it won't be taking up any more memory than an `about:blank` page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent auto-loading of tabs in Firefox when starting browser](http://superuser.com/questions/508972/prevent-auto-loading-of-tabs-in-firefox-when-starting-browser)

Comment: @CroadLangshan: Is `browser.sessionstore.restore_on_demand` set to true?

Comment: @harrymc yes `browser.sessionstore.restore_on_demand` is set to true

Comment: @CroadLangshan: Try the add-on [Load Background Tabs Lazily](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/load-background-tabs-lazily/).

Comment: That says `Allow only a specific number of new background tabs to load at one time.`  It sounds like it *serializes* tab loading (N tabs at a time are loaded, progressing until all tabs are loaded without user interaction).  I, and the original questioner I think, am rather looking for something that prevents tab loading until the tab is selected (e.g. by clicking on the tab, or by keyboard navigation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [BarTab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/bartab/), but I find it doesn't work too well with Firefox 4/5.

Another more reliable way is to use the new about:config property, `browser.sessionstore.max_concurrent_tabs`.

Go to about:config in firefox and search for `browser.sessionstore.max_concurrent_tabs`. Set the integer value to 0.

Now when you start up Firefox, only the first open tab will be opened. All the rest need to be clicked/focused on before they are actually loaded.

[image]

Comment: and also now with the Tab groups feature, FF only loads active tab group.

Answer (score 1):

As of March 2024, Firefox Version 124, that is default behavior for Firefox (it has been there for many many years, see the Edit). After a restart, Tabs will only be loaded once you actually click on them. This works on Windows, and it should work the same way on Mac or Linux (although I cannot test this).

So, go to `about:support` and click on "Refresh Firefox". that should eliminate any user setting which could interfere with such behavior.

If that should not help, try uninstalling and reinstalling.

**EDIT:**

In [this thread](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1299975) from 2020 a user asks to disable the feature, and in [this other thread](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1185154) from 2017 a related question is asked: which means that the functionality has been there for many years. More interestingly, in `about:config` there are two distinct flags:

- `browser.sessionstore.restore_on_demand` when set to `false` (default is `true`), will load all tabs on startup.
- `browser.sessionstore.restore_pinned_tabs_on_demand` will do the same only for pinned tabs.

So, by [using pinned tabs](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/pinned-tabs-keep-favorite-websites-open) you can have some of your tabs auto-load, while the others will not load on startup.

Comment: This is correct. The traffic I was seeing on firefox startup, which seemed implausibly extensive to be from anything other than tabs, was coming from the various sources here https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-stop-firefox-making-automatic-connections plus "web push", which is not listed there. To verify this (Arch Linux Firefox 124.0.1) I had to turn all that off, then set `dom.push.enabled` false to disable web push (I may have had to turn off more in addition). With all that turned off, I see only DNS traffic from firefox on startup with "Open previous windows and tabs" enabled.

Comment: Just to add: I'm not suggesting to people to turn all those off: I did that to verify the tab behaviour.  But now I mention that, it's also true there's also a lot in there that as from my user perspective provides no benefit to me, other preferences split oddly between user-visible and non-user-visible settings in ways surprising to me, and yes much that should concern anybody who worries about concentration of power and surveillance!

Comment: Do you have a citation for that?  If so I think it would be great to add it

Answer (score 0):

[BarTab](https://web.archive.org/web/20111121123745/https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/bartab/) will do this.

> BarTab can intercept when tabs are loaded in the background or restored after a browser restart and will only load the content when the tab is actually visited. It also allows you to free memory by unloading already loaded tabs, either manually or automatically.