# Is it possible to open multiple tabs but not load the URLs?

Tags: firefox, browser, bookmarks, browser-tabs

When I'm causally browsing, some pages I go to I want to view them later but I don't want them bookmarked and now and again I will bookmark all these tabs into a single folder in a backup folder, the kinds of pages would be like info pages or products on a store which I'm not sure that I want to get (and thus not add to my watch/wish list), over time I have ended up with over 400 tabs open (thanks Tab Mix Plus).

Now this has been fine when Firefox crashes since when it restores these tabs, only 1 of them is actually loaded which is good cause the network I'm on we get charged for every page that loads up with some exceptions (Wikipedia, Google), naturally.

Now recently I went to close down Firefox and when I started it up again none of the tabs was saved, I know it's proably a good thing that I don't have 400 tabs open now but there is a reason why I haven't yet gotten rid of a lot of them.

I want to get all these tabs back again but the last time something like this happened (when I had like 100 tabs) I went to the folder I stored the backup of the tabs, left clicked and went to "Open all in New Tabs", this loaded them all up and took a chunk out of my internet allowance.

So my question is: Is there a way to open multiple tabs but in a way where the URLs aren't loaded instently, that way if I want to return to a page I just click the tab and it loads?

Comment: Instead of opening the pages in different tabs, have you considered using services like Instapaper or Pocket? These will allow you to save links to read later, and you don't even have to be at the same computer. There are clients for mobile devices, too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent auto-loading of tabs in Firefox when starting browser](http://superuser.com/questions/508972/prevent-auto-loading-of-tabs-in-firefox-when-starting-browser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox Options / Tabs has a **Don't load tabs until selected** setting you can try:

[image: 1]

Comment: i have that option checked but when i load up 8 tabs (as a test) they all load up and the only difference is that the tab title is in red, normally when Firefox restores itself when it crashes the tab is like a pale yellow

Comment: According to the [official description](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/tab-preferences-and-settings), "Firefox will only load the active tab when it starts or restores your previous session. This can make startup much faster if you are restoring many tabs. The other open tabs will be loaded as you click on them." If the option doesn't help, you can try the [BarTab Lite](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/bartab-lite/) add-on.

Comment: the addon you suggested helped, now i got my 400 tabs back yay

Comment: There is no such setting in Firefox 65.