# Firefox having trouble loading websites at start up

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, browser-cache

When i start up Firefox, I try to get into amazon.com or ebay.com and the loading is just unbearable, it takes half a minute to load both of them (basically it is the same on any big site with a lot of pictures).

After it is finish loading them, I try to load them again and it is instantly loading..

When i close Firefox and start it up again (immediately) I get the same result.

I checked the cache and it is not deleted at all.. 
I dont know what is the problem but it is happening the first time I open a website the first time Firefox start up.

If you have trouble understanding what I mean (because of my poor English):

1. Firefox is closed. (firefox.exe is not activated)
2. Opening Firefox, which has the same cache as before.
3. Try to load websites like **Amazon**, **Ebay** or **IMDB**.
4. loading time takes about half a minute each.
5. closing the tabs **BUT NOT** Firefox.
6. try to load them all at once all over again.
7. Loading time take at least 1 sec each.
8. Closing Firefox.
9. Go to 1.

These are the I have:

- NoScript
- Adblock Plus
- Firebug

these are the settings:

[image]

(Don't mind the 15.1MB of cache, I deleted it manually before i opened this question)

Comment: Does this also happen in other browsers, such as Internet Explorer and Chrome? (this will tell us if its a problem with firefox or your network configuration.)

Comment: In Internet Explorer the webpages load in 30~ seconds and after that It loads in 15~ seconds (without closing it). If it is a problem with the network configuration, what can I do?

Comment: So the answer is: **Yes** it happens with other browsers.  The first step use a different DNS server.

Comment: How do I do that without causing problems with my internet? :)

Comment: I have changed my DNS server to 8.8.8.8 (google) and I still have the same problem (I have checked in the Command Prompted with the command "ipconfig /all" and The DNS Servers was 8.8.8.8 (at first it was 10.0.0.138))

Comment: Does this happen with all devices from the premises (and only the  devices going through the same router)? Has this issue always happened? If not, what has changed? What AV/Internet Security do you use? If safe to do so, pause the protection and see if the same issue persists. Are you using a proxy or similar?

Comment: Can you perform a speedtest to be sure your internet is fast enough? Also check for spyware/malware/virusses in case they slow down your network or are used as a proxy.

Comment: Looks like a DNS resolution issue; the first lookups take an eternity but then they're cached and subsequent requests are instant; the DNS cache has nothing to do with the web resource cache or cookies and is cleared each time you restart your browser.

Comment: Another issue is flaky IPv6 connections, a connection that works to establish a connection to the server (relay a small SYN and ACK packet) and then stalls due to MTU issues or similar, so the browser waits a long time for the IPv6 connection to timeout before trying IPv4.

Comment: I will check tomorrow about the other devices. Nothing has changed except MalwareBytes Anti-Exploit. I do not use proxy.
I have 40MB/s (this is what I should get), I have checked for malware or viruses i have none. @AndréDaniel so what should I do about the DNS/IPv6?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent auto-loading of tabs in Firefox when starting browser](http://superuser.com/questions/508972/prevent-auto-loading-of-tabs-in-firefox-when-starting-browser)